# Get last parameter on shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

case 1 : 
suppose I am passing a number of parameters to my shell script as follows :

```
./myshell_script a b c d
```

and if I run `echo $#` will give me number of parameters from command line I have passed and I stored it in a variable like [ since I dont know number of arguments a user is passing ]:

```
var1 = `echo "$#"`
```

case 2 :
$4 gives me the name of last argument .

if i want it to store in

var2 then

```
var2 = $4
```

My question is :

If I want to store value I get from var1 to var2 directly , how would be it possible in shell script ?

for ex :

```
./myshell_script.sh a b c

var1 = `echo "$#"` ie var1 = 3
```

now I want

var2 = c [ ie always last parameter , since I dont know how many number of parameters user is passing from comand line ]

what I have to do ?

Answer (score 11):

The script below shows how you can get the first and last arguments passed to a script:

```
numArgs="$#"
echo "Number of args: $numArgs"

firstArg="$1"
echo "First arg: $firstArg"

lastArg="${!#}"
echo "Last arg: $lastArg"
```

Output:

```
$ ./myshell_script.sh a b c d e f
Number of args: 6
First arg: a
Last arg: f
```

Comment: Where is the `${!#}` documented? Is this just a Bash feature? Is it in POSIX?

Comment: It is specific to Bash. So use it if your shebang in bash. If you need something portable, I found only the loop as suggested by @devnull.

Answer (score 8):

For this, you can use:

```
${@: -1}
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash

echo "passed $# parameters, last being --> ${@: -1}"

$ ./a a b c d
passed 4 parameters, last being --> d
$ ./a a b c d e f g
passed 7 parameters, last being --> g
```

Answer (score 5):

Quoting a way from [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-12.html):

```
for last; do : ; done
echo "${last}"
```

The last argument passed to the script would be stored in the variable `last`.

As mentioned in the link, this would work in POSIX-compatible shells it works for ANY number of arguments.

---

BTW, I doubt if your script works the way you've written in your question:

```
var1 = `echo "$#"`
```

You need to remove those spaces around `=`, i.e. say:

```
var1=`echo "$#"`
```

or

```
var1=$(echo "$#")
```

Comment: With an old Solaris, with the old bourne shell (not POSIX), I have to write "for last in "$@"; do : ; done"

Answer (score -1):

It might be better to reorganize your parameters. Instead of a variable number of arguments followed by a specific final argument, put the last argument first (so that it is `$1`), and put the variable number of arguments after that. So instead of

```
myshell_script a b c d
```

with `var2` eventually being set to "d", use

```
var2=$1; shift
```

and call like

```
myshell_script d a b c
```

Now `var2` will have the value the value of "d", and `$@` (after the shift) will contain "a", "b", and "c".

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose. It reminds me of printf in C, but what if we want to do something similar to `test` command?

Comment: That's not a great example; POSIX leaves the result of a test command specified if there are more than 4 arguments.